# How to reuse 2D array?

Tags: android, arrays

I'm working with Android accelerometer sensor data. I'm going to identify movement patterns of the user by using that sensor data. Most of the work is done. But the problem is tracking continuous axis values and storing them within a 2D array. As a test application I want to fill a `double[2][3]` array with following kind of data.

```
[9.594786195244101, 7.118138482942524, 14.240399748761671],
[9.45045389772222, 7.35019779174396, 13.271781719935262]
```

It is possible to fill the array. But the problem is, I want to re-fill the same array for getting the next set of values. Here is my code for that.

```
double[][] test;
static int sampleNumber = 1;
static int j = 1;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (started) {
        if(sampleNumber == (j*2)-1)
        {
            test = null;
            test = new double[2][3];                
            j+=1;
        }   

        test[sampleNumber-1][0] = magAvg;
        test[sampleNumber-1][1] = magMin;
        test[sampleNumber-1][2] = magMax;
        sampleNumber += 1;
    }
}
```

When executing this code, a get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException when sampleNumber = 3.
I want to create a new array or start refilling the same array when sampleNumber = 1,3,5,...

How might I do this?

Comment: you want to use the same test [2][3] array when onSensorChanged() called that you want right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating test array 2*3 anyway...
when sampleNumber = 3 you want to fill array like this:

```
test[2][0] = magAvg;
test[2][1] = magMin;
test[2][2] = magMax;
```

But you are creating test array using

```
new double[2][3]
```

then test just have 0 and 1 as indexes and accessing index=2 is out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

you can use a 2-D `ArrayList` instead of 2-D array in your case.

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`